# How can I change my functions.filter.php on a Wordpress site to fix broken link [site_url_secure]

Tags: php, wordpress

I have installed a SSL certificate on a very old WP site. The plugins and WP itself have been autoupdating but the theme is long out of date and support stopped nearly three years ago. This is the theme https://wordpress.org/themes/white/ The site is still on 1.0.1 (Sept 2014).   There have been five revisions since then, the last of them in Feb 2017. https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/log/white?limit=100&mode=stop_on_copy&format=rss . I have managed to install the certificate and updated links to https so that's OK. Unfortunately, a couple of image links are now broken - one of which is the logo! I have spent hours looking into this on the web and it would seem that this is most probably related to php (about which I know nothing). When I inspect the broken logo I see this....

```
<img alt="Featured Logo" src="[site_url_secure]/wp-content/uploads/****png">
```

A couple of years ago someone said they'd fixed the issue by

```
removing [site_url_secure] from admin>functions>functions.filter.php
```

but i don't know how to do this. Can anyone advise me please?

```
function of_filter_save_media_upload($data) {

if(!is_array($data)) return $data;   

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

    if (is_string($value)) {

        $data[$key] = str_replace(

            array(

                site_url('', 'http'),

                site_url('', 'https'),

            ),

            array(

                '[site_url]',

                '[site_url_secure]',

            ),

            $value

        );

    }

}

return $data;

}

add_filter('of_options_before_save', 'of_filter_save_media_upload');
function of_filter_load_media_upload($data) {



if(!is_array($data)) return $data;

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

    if (is_string($value) && preg_match("/\[site_url(_url_secure)?\]/", $value)) {

        $data[$key] = str_replace(

            array(

                '[site_url]', 

                '[site_url_secure]',

            ),

            array(

                site_url('', 'http'),

                site_url('', 'https'),

            ),

            $value

        );

    }

}
return $data;

}

add_filter('of_options_after_load', 'of_filter_load_media_upload');
```

Comment: Do you update the php version on your site?

Comment: It's currently on 5.1 and the host is charging a premium every month for extended support. I'd be really worried about updating php in case it broke other things.

Comment: Try to uninstall the plugin as you are installed lastly then check your code.

Answer (score 0):

resolved !
Just change:

```
preg_match("/\[site_url(_url_secure)?\]/"
```

to :

```
preg_match("/\[site_url(_secure)?\]/"
```

in your code :)

Comment: I really, really appreciate your answering this after so long, Hammed.  In the end, I had to pay for a php specialist to fix it. If this was all that was required, some good has come out of it: I will try and get to grips with php a bit more!  Thank you once again.